# Hibernate: mix annotated classes and classic hbm.cfg.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate

**someone explain the below (can and cannot) with a example?**

Hibernate docs (latest)

> You can mix annotated persistent classes and classic hbm.cfg.xml declarations with the same SessionFactory. You can however not declare a class several times (whether annotated or through hbm.xml). You cannot mix configuration strategies (hbm vs annotations) in an entity hierarchy either.

*Can we do this? property **annotatedClasses** and **mappingResources***

```
<beans:bean id="hibernateSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
        <beans:list>
            <beans:value>com.dev.spring.model.Person</beans:value>
        </beans:list>
    </beans:property>
<beans:property name="mappingResources">
<beans:list>
    <value>
        com/hibernate/abc.xml</value>
</beans:list>
```

Comment: Have you tried it? IN short yes you can.

Comment: I tried but facing some tag errors in web.xml

Comment: How is this even related to your web.xml? That doesn't change with using hbm files or annotations...